# Lotto program doesn't stop

Tags: c#

So I'm making a lotto game. You have to enter 6 lucky numbers and if they're the same as the lotto numbers then you win.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace OefeningExaam
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random getal = new Random();
            int[] lottotrekking = new int[6];

            Console.WriteLine("Geef je geluksgetallen in <tussen 1 en 42>");
            Console.WriteLine("Geef je eerste getal in");
            int getal1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Geef je tweede getal in");
            int getal2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Geef je derde getal in");
            int getal3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Geef je vierde getal in");
            int getal4 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Geef je vijfde getal in");
            int getal5 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Geef je zesde getal in");
            int getal6 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            while (getal1 != lottotrekking[0] || getal2 != lottotrekking[1] || getal3 != lottotrekking[2] || getal4 != lottotrekking[3] || getal5 != lottotrekking[4] || getal5 != lottotrekking[4] || getal6 != lottotrekking[5])
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < lottotrekking.Length; i++)
                {
                    int cijfer = getal.Next(1, 43);
                    lottotrekking[i] = cijfer;
                    Console.WriteLine(lottotrekking[0] + "\t " + lottotrekking[1] + "\t " + lottotrekking[2] + "\t " + lottotrekking[3] + "\t " + lottotrekking[4] + "\t " + lottotrekking[5]);
                }
            }

            if (getal1 == lottotrekking[0] && getal2 == lottotrekking[1] && getal3 == lottotrekking[2] && getal4 == lottotrekking[3] && getal5 == lottotrekking[4] && getal5 == lottotrekking[4] && getal6 == lottotrekking[5])
            {
                Console.WriteLine(lottotrekking[0] + " " + lottotrekking[1] + " " + lottotrekking[2] + " " + lottotrekking[3] + " " + lottotrekking[4] + " " + lottotrekking[5]);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();   
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the program just keeps going and doesn't stop. It's supposed to stop when the lucky numbers are the same as the lotto numbers.

Comment: your program is even less likely to stop than winning the lottery; it requires that the numbers are not only correct, but also in order

Comment: Wait, you guessed the right numbers? Wow! That's lucky. EDIT: Oh, nevermind, this is to try and get them right randomly? Well, you might have to wait a while... 2,744,515,872 iterations on average...

Comment: But how can i do that, i have exams tommorrow and i don't know what to do...

Comment: What is the expected flow of your program? 1) User enters 6 numbers. 2) Then the program is supposed to keep on randomly generating 6 numbers until the match the user input from 1?

Comment: The program has to stop when the user numbers are the same as the random numbers but the program never stops. the 6 given numbers have to be actually the same as the 6 random numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This generates random numbers until it matches the user input, it takes roughly 2 minutes to guess the correct numbers.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace OefeningExaam
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random getal              = new Random();
            int[]  lottotrekking      = new int[6];
            int[]  userInput          = new int[6];
            bool   isLotteryWon       = false;
            int    numberOfIterations = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Geef je geluksgetallen in <tussen 1 en 42>");
            Console.WriteLine("Geef je eerste getal in");
            userInput[0] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Geef je tweede getal in");
            userInput[1] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Geef je derde getal in");
            userInput[2] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Geef je vierde getal in");
            userInput[3] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Geef je vijfde getal in");
            userInput[4] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Geef je zesde getal in");
            userInput[5] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            while (!isLotteryWon)
            {
                isLotteryWon = true;

                // Generate the lottery numbers
                for (int i = 0; i < lottotrekking.Length; i++)
                {
                    int newNumber = getal.Next(1, 43);

                    while (Program.IsContained(lottotrekking, newNumber))
                        newNumber = getal.Next(1, 43);

                    lottotrekking[i] = newNumber;
                }


                Console.WriteLine(lottotrekking[0] + "\t " + lottotrekking[1] + "\t " + lottotrekking[2] + "\t " + lottotrekking[3] + "\t " + lottotrekking[4] + "\t " + lottotrekking[5]);

                //Compare lottery numbers to user input, if they match and are in the same order, the user wins.
                for (int i = 0; i < lottotrekking.Length; i++)
                    isLotteryWon &= Program.IsContained(lottotrekking, userInput[i]);

                numberOfIterations++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Lottery won in {0} iterations", numberOfIterations));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the specified number is contained in the collection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="collection">The collection.</param>
        /// <param name="number">The number.</param>
        /// <returns>
        ///   <c>true</c> if the specified number is contained in the collection; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
        /// </returns>
        private static bool IsContained(int[] collection, int number)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < collection.Length; i++)
            {
                if (collection[i] == number)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
I hope it helps.

Comment: But the program must randomize numbers until you win, your program just give's a reply.

Comment: And You've got it wrong. They DON'T have to be in the same order, as long as they all match

Comment: In your first post you said "You have to enter 6 lucky numbers and if they're the same as the lotto numbers then you win", so if I understand this correctly, you only need to generate the random numbers once, and the check if the user input is the same as the numbers you generated, whats the purpose of keep generating more numbers until they match?

Comment: Then you would need to change this "isLotteryWon &= lottotrekking[i] == userInput[i];" to this "isLotteryWon &= lottotrekking.Contains(userInput[i]);"

Comment: My teacher told me that i had to make a program where the user has to give in 6 numbers and then 6 random numbers. The order doesn't matter they all just have to be in the random lotto numbers. And after the computer has generated the same numbers, the program has to tell us how many lotto pulls you needed before the user numbers where the same as the random numbers.

Comment: Oh i see, well thats gonna take a WHILE, with your current set up (42 possible numbers in six slots) there are millions of possible combinations, so the odds of the random generated numbers on matching the input are very low.

Comment: [IMG]http://i49.tinypic.com/33bon54.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: [IMG]http://i47.tinypic.com/hx3z12.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: [IMG]http://i50.tinypic.com/15xpwsj.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: first screen is where you give your numbers, second is the ramdom numbers being generated, third is the screen with  how many times it needed for you to win the lottery

Comment: [IMG]http://i48.tinypic.com/35cn85t.png[/IMG] There, it took about 2 minutes to guess, I'll upload the source in the answer.

Comment: Can i replace the .contains with something else?

Comment: Why cant you use contains? xD, you can do it manually, make a method that iterate over the collection, if it finds the element return true, otherwise return false. Btw if you found this answer useful plz rate it or accept it :D.

Comment: yeah :p , we didn't learn this at school so i have to replace it but with what?

Comment: Just add a method that do the iteration and compare, I updated the code in the answer, changed the contains with a "IsContained(int[] collection, int number)", you pass the array and the number you want to find, and it retursn true if the number is in the collection, false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work. But it will probably take a while to match all numbers.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random getal = new Random();
            int[] lottotrekking = new int[6];

            var getals = new List<int>();

            Console.WriteLine("Geef je geluksgetallen in <tussen 1 en 42>");
            Console.WriteLine("Geef je eerste getal in");
            getals.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
            Console.WriteLine("Geef je tweede getal in");
            getals.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
            Console.WriteLine("Geef je derde getal in");
            getals.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
            Console.WriteLine("Geef je vierde getal in");
            getals.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
            Console.WriteLine("Geef je vijfde getal in");
            getals.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
            Console.WriteLine("Geef je zesde getal in");
            getals.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));


            bool match = false;
            while (!match)
            {
                //Reset the array
                lottotrekking = new int[6];
                for (int i = 0; i < lottotrekking.Length; i++)
                {

                    //Make sure we dont add one number several times
                    int cijfer = 0;
                    while (lottotrekking.Any(x => x == cijfer) || cijfer == 0)
                    {
                        cijfer = getal.Next(1, 43);
                    }
                    lottotrekking[i] = cijfer;

                }
                Console.WriteLine(lottotrekking[0] + "\t " + lottotrekking[1] + "\t " + lottotrekking[2] + "\t " + lottotrekking[3] + "\t " + lottotrekking[4] + "\t " + lottotrekking[5]);

                match = lottotrekking.All(getals.Contains);

            }

            Console.WriteLine(lottotrekking[0] + " " + lottotrekking[1] + " " + lottotrekking[2] + " " + lottotrekking[3] + " " + lottotrekking[4] + " " + lottotrekking[5]);


            Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }
```

Comment: I think i should use a break somewhere ?

Comment: Why would you do that? The loops will break eventually. I.e when match is true.

Comment: your program is just the same as mine ... it never stops :s

Comment: It will stop way ahead of yours. The numbers don't has to be at the same place. 1 = 1 no matter of position in the array.